# Como criar Procedure em PL/SQL, Passando CPF como paramento e retorna 1 se for a data de aniversário do CPF informado e 0 se não for

Tags: pl-sql

Como eu criou essa procedure em PL/SQL?

eu criei em SQL SERVER, está funcionando porém, preciso criar também em PL/SQL.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DataAniversario]
(
     @CPF VARCHAR(20)
    
)
AS
  SELECT * FROM Clientes 
             where CPF = @CPF
      
  IF(@CPF='1')

    BEGIN

    SELECT * from Clientes where DAY(MONTH(DataAniversario)) = DAY(MONTH(GETDATE()))
    and CPF = @CPF
    
        RETURN 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
```

Eu passo o CPF, e verifica se hoje é data de aniversário do CPF informado.

para testar estou disponibilizando as tabelas com dados

```sql
 CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."TB_CLIENTES" 
   (    "ID_CLIENTE" NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
    "CPF" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "NOME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ENDERECO1" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "ENDERECO2" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "BAIRRO" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CIDADE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "ESTADO" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CEP" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "IDADE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DATA_ANIVERSARIO" DATE, 
    "SEXO" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "LIMITE_CREDEITO" FLOAT(126), 
    "VOLUME_COMPRA" FLOAT(126), 
    "PRIMEIRA_COMPRA" NUMBER(1,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
REM INSERTING into SYSTEM.TB_CLIENTES
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into SYSTEM.TB_CLIENTES (ID_CLIENTE,CPF,NOME,ENDERECO1,ENDERECO2,BAIRRO,CIDADE,ESTADO,CEP,IDADE,DATA_ANIVERSARIO,SEXO,LIMITE_CREDEITO,VOLUME_COMPRA,PRIMEIRA_COMPRA) values ('1','87220630050','Jose Cipriano',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,to_date('11/07/84','DD/MM/RR'),null,null,null,null);
Insert into SYSTEM.TB_CLIENTES (ID_CLIENTE,CPF,NOME,ENDERECO1,ENDERECO2,BAIRRO,CIDADE,ESTADO,CEP,IDADE,DATA_ANIVERSARIO,SEXO,LIMITE_CREDEITO,VOLUME_COMPRA,PRIMEIRA_COMPRA) values ('2','78301914092','Fuampa Bezerra',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,to_date('06/11/84','DD/MM/RR'),null,null,null,null);
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index SYS_C007302
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYSTEM"."SYS_C007302" ON "SYSTEM"."TB_CLIENTES" ("ID_CLIENTE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table TB_CLIENTES
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."TB_CLIENTES" MODIFY ("ID_CLIENTE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."TB_CLIENTES" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CLIENTE")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE;
```

Comment: esse código mesmo em SQL não faz o que diz to título da pergunta, não está validando se encontrou o CPF e a data é hoje

Comment: Qual o sentido de você aplicar a função `DAY` ao resultado da função `MONTH`? Talvez você queira: `DAY(DataAniversario) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(DataAniversario) = MONTH(GETDATE())`.

Comment: Ricardo, você está certo, mas a consultar no SQL server atende, porque verifica o dia e Mês, assim como a sua função que informou acima também, vai retorna corretamente. Você consegue me ajudar com PL SQL.

Comment: essa condição  DAY(DataAniversario) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(DataAniversario) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
  é o mesmo que:
where DAY(MONTH(DataAniversario)) = DAY(MONTH(GETDATE()))

consegue ajudar a desenvolver o Procedure em PLSQL?

Comment: A função `DAY`, assim como `MONTH`, espera receber um parâmetro do tipo `DATE` mas ambas as funções retornam um `INTEGER`, portanto utilizar o resultado da função MONTH como parâmetro da função DAY certamente não dará o resultado esperado.

Comment: anonimo, ok, entendi, consegue me ajudar ? como fica essa procedure em PLSQL?